# Azure ARM latest SDK

Tags: azure

Please give some details about the latest released version of ARM SDK. Because i could see the MVN repository having 0.9.4 , beta1 and beta2 versions. Please suggest which version going to be stable.

In GitHub link do not have java-docs for 0.9.4 version release. Please share the link for the same.
I referred the below link but it is having v0.9, 0.9.3, beta1 and beta1+fixes releases.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java

I referred the link to download SDK. But it is having only 0.9.0 like (azure-svc-mgmt-0.9.0) version

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

Why the latest version SDK documentation not uploaded in azure site. Please give me some suggestion to get rid of this. Which version last stable release?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Rathidevi

Answer (score 0):

Recently azure has released 1.0.0 as stable release and this Java SDK version is the latest stable version.

This version has changed drastically compared to older stable versions such as 0.9.0.

I would recommend you to upgrade you to new Java SDK version 1.0.0.